# App started with a custom url scheme does not appear in recent apps list

Tags: android

When my app is started with a custom url scheme it does not appear in the "recent apps" list (appears on holding the home button).

Example:

1. I start my app from a link in an SMS. My app launches. This is **ok**.
2. Then I press the Home button and go to the home screen. Still **ok**.
3. Then I hold the Home button and the list of recent apps appears. My app is not on the list. This in **not ok** - I would expect my app to be on this list.
4. If I select the Messaging app from the list my app comes up. This is **not ok**. I would expect to see the Messaging app instead.

*AndroidManifest.xml*:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">

  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>

  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:host="myhost.com" android:scheme="http" android:pathPattern="/Y.*"/>
  </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what's happening is that your activity is being launched with an affinity to the task (application) that launched it, rather than launching a new task (your application).

Try setting the [`launchMode`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) of your activity to `singleInstance` (the default is `standard`).

i.e.:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:launchMode="singleInstance">
```

(Note: check the above linked `launchMode` documentation as you may prefer `singleTask` over `singleInstance` depending on what you are trying to achieve with your application.)

Comment: I tried setting the launchMode to singleInstance and singleTask, but then my app started "behaving weird". The _not recommended for general use_ note in the documentation discouraged me from experimenting further with it.

Comment: Hmm, fair enough. Without knowing what 'behaving weird' means it's hard to tell whether you're on the right track or not.

Have you tried setting [`taskAffinity`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#aff) to something like `com.yourpackage.yourActivity`?